# How to allow users In Django to see specific data from same model

Tags: django, permissions

I am facing a problem while giving permission to admin users in Django that how to restrict users to see only user specific data from same model. I mean that if 2 user can add data to same model, then how to restrict them to access only that data.

Answer (score 0):

in that model you need to specify which user inserted that value. If you have User model, then you can add new field to your model as User which is ForeignKey field.

When you inserted your data with user property, you can easily filter them with user (user.id)

For example if you have Customer model you can filter the value with user's id (in this case it's merchant_id):

```
        customer = Customer.objects.filter(email=email, merchant_id=merchant_id).all()
```

And our model looks like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model):

merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

and you can define a permissions like:

```
class Task(models.Model):
...
class Meta:
    permissions = [
        ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
        ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as closed"),
    ]
```

and you can check that via:

```
user.has_perm('app.close_task')
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Sir I am taking about admin permission given to those users which is added by admin. In my project users works is an subadmin. If a subadmin add something into a model then how to restrict other user(subadmins) to access that post. Rather then to access its own posts. Customizing permission.